# WIFI router configurations

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I have installed a virtual server on my PC linked to internet via static IP. But whenever I try to access server through net via static IP, it takes me to the router login page. Can anyone help me in setting up router configurations? I have  a D link WIFI router.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use your internal ip address along with port forwarding.

Comment: i am unable to do port forwarding. it says external port not in rang

Comment: @user311632 Did you use a port number from 0 to 65535?

Comment: @user311632 Why didn't you describe your problem when you asked your question?

Comment: my problem is that i am unable to do it. I have tried port forwarding, but unable to do it. I have also unsuccessful ly tried DMZ.  I am stil unable to do portforwarding using ports 0 to 65535

Comment: What are you using this for?

Comment: i have installed a virtual server on my PC for teleradiology. When I try to access that using my static IP, it takes me to router page..